# How to set a blank property

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings

I'm trying to configure Android M

I would like to set erase a persistent property like

```
getprop | grep dhcp
.../...
[dhcp.wlan0.domain]: [acme.com]
.../..
```

I would like this property became like this :

```
[dhcp.wlan0.domain]: []
```

I tried the `setprop` command with a blank argument and I got an error message :

```
 setprop dhcp.wlan0.domain 
usage: setprop NAME VALUE

Sets an Android system property.

setprop: Need 2 arguments
```

I tried `[]` as argument and the property has been changed like this :

```
 [dhcp.wlan0.domain]: [[]]
```

I believe this last  property is occurring error

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass an empty value, you need to pass an "empty string" – which is usually specified by two quote marks with nothing between them. For your specific command this would look like

```
setprop dhcp.wlan0.domain ""
```